# Values on minkowski square of rational ellipsoid

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, quadratic-forms

Let $q(x)$ be positive-definite rational quadratic form. Let $C_q$ be the following set:

$$C_q = \{q(x + y) \quad | \quad q(x) = q(y) = 1\}$$

Is it true or not that set $C_q$ defines the equivalence class of form $q$, i.e. two rational forms $q_1$ and $q_2$ are rationally equivalent iff $C_{q_1} = C_{q_2}$?